# Is influx DB a good choice to aggregate a certain amount of events that happened during a timeframe

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying out InfluxDB to know if my usecase fits.

My app generates a bunch of events like product created, product deleted, product purchased, payment recieved, category created etc. Each event has some other properties such as who created the product or what the payment method was...

I want to know how many products were purchased or howmany payments were done using a specific payment method or howmany payments were done for a day or till now or with in a time specified. Same for all the events like payment, shipping etc. I am yet to understand the concept of TSDB. Every example I see has some value that is varying, ie; temperature 23,30,23,35,24,33 and so on. In my app each event has a value of 1, since each event contibute to one unit of that event.

Is InfluxDB a good choice for this usecase ? If yes, How would I model my data for use cases like this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use TSDB for your e-commerce analysis but it might be better to try data warehouse instead, especially when your data volume grows rapidly.

TSDB are best used with time series data plus time series analysis. For example, if you care when the shopping cart is filled and emptied but don't care that much about what is in the shopping cart.

Your use case is more like OLAP and you could check out [ClickHouse](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/about-us/adopters/).